# Is there a way to skip checking if package exists when publishing artifact to feed?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an azure pipeline that at the end creates azure artifacts out of my deliverables.
I then publish them to azure feeds so other pipelines can use them.

I have been facing error `An unexpected error occurred while trying to push the package. Exit code(17)`.
Looking at the log I can see it claims `The package myPackage 1.0122.0 already exists in myUuidString`.

1. Is there a way to bypass the check whether the package exists or not ? In other words, is not there a way to overwrite a package in case it exists?
2. Is there a way to clear/delete the contents of a feed before publishing?

Could not find neither answer in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/universal-packages?view=azure-devops).

Comment: Why just not increase the version number?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk: Hey Shay, we must be doing something non standard here. We currently use the same pipeline to release testing and production versions. So I would run it, say, 10 times during development for testing, but I do not want the version to be incremented. The packages should however be published to feed because another pipeline uses them.

Comment: @Veverke, If you want the version of the package to remain unchanged and the package to be updated, the package will use the local cache first because the package is cached locally by the engineer. In this case, even if you update the package, due to the package version There is no change, the local cache will still be used on the engineer side, which creates a risk of confusion. This is why the feed has to guarantee the only version of the package

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to skip checking if package exists when publishing artifact to feed?

For the [Universal Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/universal-packages?view=azure-devops) task, I am farid there is no such way to skip checking if package exists when publishing artifact to feed at this moment.

Unlike the nuget push task, there is currently no such option for the Universal Package task to allow duplicates to be skipped:

[image]

Besides, since the document: [Understand immutability of packages](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/feeds/immutability):

> **Once you publish a particular version of a package to a feed, that
> version number is permanently reserved. You cannot upload a newer
> revision package with that same version number, or delete it and
> upload a new package at the same version**.

So, we could not updalod the same version to the feed.

As workaround, we could publish the package with a new version. And we could add a user voice for the same option **Allow duplicates to be skipped** on the [Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks).